# How to plot complex outputs of an NSolve function?

Tags: plotting, complex

For instance, if I input

```
NSolve[x^2+1==x,x,WorkingPrecision->30]
```

the output is

```
{{x -> 0.500000000000000000000000000000 - 0.866025403784438646763723170753 I}, 
{x -> 0.500000000000000000000000000000 + 0.866025403784438646763723170753 I}}
```

Is there some function I can use to get this to automatically plotted? Such that if I enter `output = NSolve[(some function)]`, I can then input the variable 'output' so that all outputs given are plotted.

Comment: What is it you want to see? A couple of points in the complex plane?

Comment: Yes, whichever ones are the outputs